# Redirect http to https on Tomcat 7 application

Tags: ssl, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a webapp application running on Tomcat7 which connects easily via https but returns Unable to connect error when accessed without it.
Below is my server.xml file content

```
<Service name="Catalina"> 
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
port="443"
maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="/usr/share/.keystore"
```

Host is Amazon lightsail and port 80 and 443 are available. I noticed port 80 which is meant to enable non-http traffic is not in use. 443 is anyway.
I have tried other methods on SO and other blogs, none seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,
I stumbled on what could have been the troubling issue.

After adding the connector code for port 80 and redirecting to 443.
I changed this section of my code to

```
<Service name="Catalina">
**<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"**
maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="/usr/share/.keystore"
keystorePass="xxx111!!"
```

And editing the web.xml file as always advised. I guessed the major change was in the code section below.

Hoping this helps someone out there.